# MySQL - compare percentages with join

Tags: mysql, left-join, percentage

I have two tables (Master and tags) and the following SQL:

```
select t.label, m.demographic_sex, count(*) from 
Master m
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags t ON t.interaction_id = m.interaction_id
where m.demographic_sex is not null
group by t.label, m.demographic_sex
;
```

This outputs:

```
label           demographic_sex     count(*)
------------------------------
label_a         Female  117845
label_a         Male    45966
BOTH            Female  6476
BOTH            Male    4406
label_b         Female  364984
label_b         Male    261089
```

How can I calculate a percentage for each gender for each label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT t.label, m.demographic_sex, COUNT(*), COUNT(*) / total_t.total_cnt
FROM Master m LEFT OUTER JOIN tags t ON t.interaction_id = m.interaction_id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT label, COUNT(*) AS total_cnt
                FROM tags
                GROUP BY label
    ) total_t ON total_t.label = t.label
WHERE m.demographic_sex is not null
GROUP BY t.label, m.demographic_sex ;
```

`total_t` has total count for each `label`.

Comment: Great stuff! Results look ideal. Many thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

you can put it into a subquery and join a total count to it then calculate the avg.

```
SELECT t.*, t.sex_count / t1.total_count as AVG_PER
FROM(
    select t.label, m.demographic_sex, count(*) as sex_count from 
    Master m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tags t ON t.interaction_id = m.interaction_id
    where m.demographic_sex is not null
    group by t.label, m.demographic_sex
) t
JOIN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count FROM Master m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tags t ON t.interaction_id = m.interaction_id
    where m.demographic_sex is not null
    group by m.demographic_sex
) t1 ON t1.label = t.label
    GROUP BY t.label, t.demographic_sex
```

if you could post some relevant data I can try and work up a more simple solution.. but without that I can't test the data. so I won't be able to guarantee the outcome